# How i use bit coin api with my project?

Tags: client, bitcoind

How to use bitcoin api in my code  or how i integrate it with my code ?
it required any charge ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the Bitcoin API, you need to either run bitcoind, or run Bitcoin QT with a `server` parameter and also having RPC username and password set ([in bitcoin.conf file](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin)). After that, you communicate with it over JSON RPC at port 8332 (by default).